# I need to push data to browser of all clients which are currently browsing our web page

Tags: php, ajax

We are making a app with php in which we want to push data to client browser same in the way in which facebook notificaiton sent by facebook. i know about commet and also have used ajax in past but ajax is not efficeint while commet programing is out of my mind.

```
Sample can seen at ESPNCRICINFO.COM live scorecard which is automatically pushed
by server to brwoser and than append to document without refreshing. Same app we
have to made.
```

Simply i need to build some code that send data to all the browser which have our webpage opened. No restrictions. Just need to send to all. So there is no need to check to whom data will be push.

I really need it urgently.

Comment: Check out [pusher.com](http://pusher.com) or [hydna.com](http://hydna.com), it's really simple.

Comment: look at node.js
Alternatively, have some javascript checking a url every minute and whenever that url contains data, it alerts it or inserts into dom or does something with it. (this is a pull not a push). If you need something urgent. Otherwise look at doing push with node.js

Comment: Sir i know all this but want to make it simple and totally free because our app will have unlimited users and almost more than 1 lac time data to be pushed to browser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

can you use JavaScript `setTimeout(function name, seconds)` ?

In JavaScript function you can generate .post request for some PHP script which can load messages, when the message will load, you can show it via you JavaScript. the timer will call this function for all people.

Comment: can you store the messages in XML ?

Comment: may be you can use sessions for pass the data and show it via JS - $.session.get("myVar")